# Given $AB$, determine uniqueness of $BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Consider $A$ being a $n$ by $r$ matrix and $B$ being a $r$ by $n$ matrix. Under what conditions for $AB$ is $BA$ unique.

This question is derived from the observation that for a matrix $C = AB$ having rank $r$ and a nonzero constant multiple of an idempotent matrix, $BA$ is unique. The question is asking if above conditions necessary to gurantee uniqueness.

Comment: "Unique"...in **what sense**?

Comment: There does not exist $A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ such that $AB =A_1B_1=A_2B_2$ but $B_1A_1 \neq B_2A_2$

Comment: I still don't follow: for $\;1\times1\;$ matrices, we can take $\;A=1\;,\;\;B=4\;$ , so $\;AB=BA=4\;$ . But there are also $\;A'=2=B'\;$ with $\;A'B'=B'A'=4\;$  .... does this mean $\;BA\;$ is unique or not unique? I think the second one (not unique), but then I don't understand your definition of "unique" .

Comment: If $A'=B'=2$, $A'B'=B'A' = 4$. For this case it is unique.

Comment: @S Thanks, I think I understand a little better your definition.